# LinkedIn Api: I'm getting "Access to people search denied."

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn Api, to search for people information,

I'm keep hit the limits per user. 
(even though I want only public info, it seems it is mandatory to send request with a logged-in user token).

So I register some people to my app, to get more tokens, but when I use the tokens, I'm getting:
**"Access to people search denied."**

What can be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info is provided to solve the problem but LinkedIn has clear documentation on their [throttle limits](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/throttle-limits).  It's never been a problem for me so I think you may be making unnecessary API calls.  I know that the data that the API returns is very deeply nested and you may not need to make so many API calls to get the data you need.  I would print one single API response to a terminal and inspect the data.  I use Python and will usually have to dig 3 or 4 levels to get the data I need. Ex.

```
updates = app.get_company_updates(COMPANY_ID, params={'count': count, 'event-type': 'status-update',})

update_list = []
for update in updates['values']:
    my_dict = {'comment': update['updateContent']['companyStatusUpdate']['share']['comment']}
    if update['updateContent']['companyStatusUpdate']['share'].get('content'):
        my_dict['description'] = update['updateContent']['companyStatusUpdate']['share']['content'].get('description')
        my_dict['submittedImageUrl'] = update['updateContent']['companyStatusUpdate']['share']['content'].get('submittedImageUrl')
        my_dict['title'] = update['updateContent']['companyStatusUpdate']['share']['content'].get('title')
        my_dict['shortenedUrl'] = update['updateContent']['companyStatusUpdate']['share']['content'].get('shortenedUrl')
    update_list.append(my_dict)
```

But if you really need to hit the API a lot then you might want to set up a bunch of scripts to run on a cron jobs daily with each script using a unique developer login.